# Matching url with Angular 8 Routing cause errors in build production

Tags: angular, routes

I have app which runs smoothly, but when I try to build production, I got below error:

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'ViewModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'matcher' was called.
```

Which cause by below code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewComponent } from './view.component';
export function matcher(replace):any {
    const checker = function(url){
        if(url[0].path.toLowerCase().indexOf(replace)>-1){
            return {
                consumed: url,
                posParams: {
                    project_id: new UrlSegment(url[0].path.toLowerCase().replace(replace, ''), {})
                }
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
    return checker;
}
const routes: Routes = [{
    component: ViewComponent,
    path: '',
    children: [{
        path:  ':project_id',
        matcher:  matcher('i-'),
        loadChildren: () => import('app/create.module').then(m => m.CreateModule)

    }]
}];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ ViewComponent],
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
})
export class ViewModule { }
```

which match the url and if it's start with `i-` then we load `CreateModule` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call the function, only provide the function.

```js
export function matcher(url: UrlSegment[]): any {
    const checker = function(url){
        if(url[0].path.toLowerCase().indexOf('i')>-1){
            return {
                consumed: url,
                posParams: {
                    project_id: new UrlSegment(url[0].path.toLowerCase().replace('i, ''), {})
                }
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
    return checker;
}

const routes: Routes = [{
    component: ViewComponent,
    path: '',
    children: [{
        path:  ':project_id',
        matcher
        loadChildren: () => import('app/create.module').then(m => m.CreateModule)

    }]
```

Your matcher function should have the signature `matcher(url: UrlSegment[]) : UrlMatchResult`

For more information, take a look at the Angular documentation for this topic:
https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher

Comment: I didn't understood first piece of code, `matcher` without value give syndax error.
I tried different kind of second, `matcher: () => matcher('i-'),` is not helping and also tried something like `const checker = function(url: UrlSegment[]) : UrlMatchResult{` in export but also didn't worked out.
Thank you in advance for interest

Comment: If your function is called matcher and takes a variable of type `UrlSegment[]`, you can simply pass it in like in my first example. Why is the anonymous function not helping?

Comment: Having same error with before with anonymous function. Try to reproduce your first case.

Comment: Please see my edit, maybe there's a misunderstanding. I reproduced this locally and the prod build runs fine.

Comment: I have an issue with above, when I use `return [ consumed: null]` angular route throw error `length of null` and in router code is show something like: `lastChild: (/** @type {?} */ (res.consumed.length)),`.
If I return directly null, those pages never show up, even if url is correct, basically each function is called only once.

Comment: That was just an example, of course you need to use  whatever functionality you need in your matcher, like in your initial question.